# I need a Simple image uploader with a simple screen. WP default has too many options.

Tags: metabox, uploads, media, images

Hi guys I'm looking for a metabox type plugin that can upload ONE image into the post, that works with custom post types.

I don't want to use the default WP uploader because it has too many options, like file url, image url, etc. It is too confusing for customers who are not familiar with WP. So I need something simple. A simple metabox.

All the plugins I was able to find use the default WP media uploader which as I said has too many options.

Anyone know of a plugin I can use for that? Free or paid.

The closest one I found was Magic Fields but it doesn't support custom post types AND it uses a custom folder to store files.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like I found one. SB Uploader.

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like I found one. [SB Uploader](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sb-uploader/).

Now I need to figure out how to use it in my theme.

The get_post_meta is a little fuzzy to me